# FFmpeg scale and overlay multiple images/gif on image in android issue?

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am trying to place multiple images/gif on image. I had tried placing single gif on image or video and its working perfectly fine but not able to work with multiple images with simultaneous scaling. Tried below code but getting error:

```
        String[] command=new String[13];
        command[0]="-i";
        command[1]=input;
        command[2]="-i";
        command[3]=thumbnail2;
        command[4]="-i";
        command[5]=thumbnail;
        command[6]="filter_complex";
        command[7]="[0:v]scale=0:0[base]";
        command[8]="[1:v]scale=30:-1[img1]";
        command[9]="[2:v]scale=3000:-1[img2]";
        command[10]="[base][img1]overlay=70:70[tmp1]";
        command[11]="[tmp1][img2]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/2[out]";

        command[12]="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/logo-2000.gif";
        fFmpeg.execute(command,
                new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onStart() {
                        //for logcat
                        Log.w(TAG,"Cut started");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(String message) {
                       Log.w(TAG,message.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(String message) {

                        Log.w(TAG,message.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String message) {

                        Log.w(TAG,message.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sucessfully saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {

                        Log.w(TAG,"Cutting video finished");
                    }
                });
```

Error I am getting is:

[NULL @ 0xb6591800] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'filter_complex'
filter_complex: Invalid argument

As I am new to ffmpeg please help me to resolve the issue I just want to scale and overlay multiple images simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

1. Use `-filter_complex` instead of `filter_complex`
2. pass the filterchain as *one* argument to `-filter_complex`

So instead of:

```
...
command[6]="filter_complex";
command[7]="[0:v]scale=0:0[base]";
command[8]="[1:v]scale=30:-1[img1]";
...
```

Do:

```
...
command[6]="-filter_complex";
command[7]="[0:v]scale=0:0[base];[1:v]scale=30:-1[img1];...";
...
```

As you can see, all filters need to be specified in one item.

Comment: Tysm, tried the code.It is working perfectly fine.What if I need to specify angle for each input ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by specifying an angle. Do you want to rotate input? Use the rotate filter: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rotate